# Solr - Reverse deep paging

Tags: solr, solr4

I want pagination feature in my app where the user can go to next and previous pages.
Paging in Solr using cursorMark gives only the nextCursorMark. How to get the previous cursors? What is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to remember previous cursor mark, similar question is answered here,

[Solr: Use Cursor in pagination to get previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735081/solr-use-cursor-in-pagination-to-get-previous-page)